# What does "integer at offset 60" mean in SQLite documentation for the `user_version? pragma`

Tags: ios, sqlite

In the [SQLite documentation for the `user_version` pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) it says:

> The user_version pragma will to get or set the value of the user-version integer at offset 60 in the database header.

What does it mean by "integer at offset 60"? My intention was to use this variable to store my application's schema version. Is this variable formatted as a 32 bit unsigned integer?

Answer (score 0):

"integer at offset 60" is reffering to the byte offset in the SQLite database's header. So if you were to get all the bytes in the database's header, and then move to byte number 60, that would be the beginning of the `user_version` pragma. And because it is 4 bytes in size (32 bits), you know that it will occupy bytes 60-63.

For reference here is [the documentation for the database header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header). If you scroll down to the row where the value in the 'Offset' column is 60, you'll see they indicate this space is dedicated for the `user_version` pragma.